# $this->_view sin declarar antes $_view?

Tags: php

Tengo una duda sobre cómo está construido este constructor: ¿Se puede hacer `$this->_view` sin haber declarado `$_view` antes? ¿Lo toma como una variable sin necesidad de declararlo antes?

```
abstract class Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_view = new View(new Request);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué no haces la prueba? Monta un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente qué quieres obtener e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Incorporar el error que obtengas, ayudará a los buscadores a indexar la pregunta y que resulte útil a más programadores.

Comment: Estás en una clase, por tanto llama a cada cosa por su nombre. En ese contexto `_view` no sería una variable sino un miembro, campo o propiedad de la clase. Generalmente, si tienes declarada una propiedad `_view` al hacer eso en el constructor, esa propiedad se convertirá en una instancia de la clase `View` con el parámetro `Request`.

Comment: (@A.Cedano) Gracias, pero ese miembro , campo o propiedad (yo lo entiendo por propiedad de una clase) ¿no debería ser primero declarada fuera y antes del constructor? En el ejemplo que yo estoy viendo esta propiedad _view no está declarada y por eso me desconcierta. Por eso estoy haciendo esta pregunta ¿Se puede acceder a una propiedad con $this->_propiedad sin haberla declarado antes? Quiza se puede hacer en un solo paso y yo desconozco por no haberlo visto antes.

Comment: Siendo que es una clase abstracta, existe sin duda en relación con otra clase. Para poder ayudarte mejor quizá convenga que indiques con qué clases está relacionada y cómo se relacionan y se usan en el programa. [Puedes leer aquí](http://www.zentut.com/php-tutorial/php-abstract-class/) para entender un poco más sobre las clases abstractas.